# getParent() is null in onResume inside TabHost child activity

Tags: android, android-activity, nullpointerexception, android-tabhost, childactivity

I have a tabhost widget which starts different activies by using Intents.

```
TabSpec tab = mTabHost.newTabSpec("profile");
tab.setIndicator("profile");
Intent i3 = new Intent(ctx, ProfileActivity.class);
tab.setContent(i3);
mTabHost.addTab(tab);
```

All childs are defined as embeded:

```
    <activity android:exported="false" android:name="com.example.app.ProfileActivity" android:label="ProfileActivity view">
       <intent-filter>
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.EMBED"></category>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"></action>
       </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Unfortunately I can see an occasional crash inside my ProfileActivity onResume function.

It crashes on this line, because `getParent()` returns null.

```
((MainActivity) getParent()).goToTab("splash")
```

It's not happening all the time - it's very occasional.

Anyone had this problem?

Comment: can you paste onResume() method>

Comment: I have added exact crash line.

Comment: The documentation states - `Return the parent activity if this view is an embedded child.` - is this the case?

Comment: @g00dy I think it's an embedded child since it's started inside apphost.

Comment: I think it becomes embedded when you `addView` or `addTab`. In the `onResume` I suppose you don't have it, please check if so.

Comment: You mean onResume of MainActivity right? I have addTab inside onCreate method in MainActivity - could this lead to a problem?

Answer (score 0):

As Documentation says: `public final Activity getParent ()` Since: API Level 1

Returns the parent activity if this view is an embedded child.

Is your Activity an embedded child? If yes then it will return parent activity context otherwise `null`

Comment: If you read closer description to my question you will see that this null is occassional and not permanent. I get parent context 99% of the time.